# Ternary operator evaluation rules in templates different?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, ternary-operator

Given this innocent snippet:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t bit  = (1ull << n);
template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t mask = (n == 64) ? ~0ull : bit<n> - 1;

namespace this_works_fine
{
    template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t bit  = (1ull << n);
    template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t mask = []() constexpr {  if constexpr (n == 64) return ~0ull; else return bit<n> - 1; }();
}

int main()
{
  auto a = mask<64>;
  (void)a;
}
```

... I expected that to "just work, zero errors, zero warnings". It's quite clear and simple and there's not much room for doing something wrong. The only thing to be aware of is that shifting more than an integer's width is UB (happens for `N == 64`), but that is being explicitly taken care of. It'll probably produce a warning/error for values larger than 64, but that's fine, no need for an explicit error check.

The conditional operator only evaluates **either** the second **or** the third operand based on the first operand's evaluation. So as long as the code altogether is in principle *syntactically* correct, we're good to go.

Now, GCC (9.1.0) tells me the following:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2 --std=c++17 -c main.cpp -o obj\main.o
g++.exe  -o lib\gcc-bug.exe obj\main.o -s 
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr const uint64_t bit<64>':
main.cpp:4:73:   required from 'constexpr const uint64_t mask<64>'
main.cpp:14:12:   required from here
main.cpp:3:59: error: right operand of shift expression '(1 << 64)' is >= than the precision of the left operand [-fpermissive]
    3 | template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t bit  = (1ull << n);
      |                                                     ~~~~~~^~~~~
```

The exact same thing rewritten with `if constexpr()` instead compiles (and, of course, works) without any trouble. No error, no warning. No surprise. Why wouldn't it work!

While I was about to submit a bug report to GCC which is "obviously broken", it occurred to me that I might first check with version 9.2 (which isn't available for MinGW yet) as well as `trunk` on Godbolt, and while we're at it with Clang as well since that's just one more click.

Unsurprisingly, the other GCC versions produce the same error, but much to my surprise, Clang doesn't compile it either. It claims that `(1ull << n)` is not a constant expression. Which is another story, but equally stunning.

So I'm a bit unsettled there. It seems like I am not understanding the rules of the conditional operator correctly? Is there any special exception for templates or template variables where it evaluates differently?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `if constexpr` then this part of the code

```
else return bit<n> - 1;
```

is not instantiated when n is equal to 64.

From the C++ Standard (9.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 If the if statement is of the form if constexpr, the value of the
>   condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of
>   type bool (8.6); this form is called a constexpr if statement. If the
>   value of the converted condition is false, the first substatement is a
>   discarded statement, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is
>   a discarded statement. During the instantiation of an enclosing
>   templated entity (Clause 17), **if the condition is not
>   value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement
>   (if any) is not instantiated.**

Opposite to this code all parts of the code

```
template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t mask = (n == 64) ? ~0ull : bit<n> - 1;
```

are instantiated. So the compiler issues an error.

Just try the following semantically equivalent code and you will get the same error.

```
#include <cstdint>

template <unsigned int n> constexpr uint64_t bit  = (1ull << n);

template uint64_t bit<64>;

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: The fact that it works with `constexpr if` doesn't surprise me at all. The fact that it _doesn't work_ with `?:` does. The whole expression is certainly instantiated, no doubt. So it must be syntactically correct, etc. (for example, it cannot contain an undefined type). But my understanding of `[expr.cond] 1` is that `(1ull<<64)` is never, not ever, under any circumstances **evaluated**. Which means there can be no error (plus, it surprises me that clang deems a shift by a template parameter not-a-constant-expression). So many troubles with so little seemingly easy and trivial code.